# Using opacus try to train a dp model, but meet `TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'module'`

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, typeerror

I am using opacus for dp training a model with the following code. However, there is a bug when running PrivacyEngine line.

```
        transformed_data = self.table.transform(dataframe)
        loader = DataLoader(transformed_data, batch_size=self.batch_size, shuffle=True)
        self.optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters())
        # self.privacy_engine = PrivacyEngine(accountant="rdp", secure_mode=True)
        # self.privacy_engine = PrivacyEngine()
        self.net, self.optim, self.train_data = PrivacyEngine(accountant="rdp", # error secure_mode=True).make_private_with_epsilon( \
            module = self.net,\
            optimizer = self.optim,\
            data_loader = loader,\
            target_epsilon=self.epsilon_target,\
            target_delta=self._delta,\
            epochs=self.epoch_target,\
            max_grad_norm=self.max_grad_norm,\
            poisson_sampling=True,\
        )
        for epoch_idx in range(self.start_epoch, self.epochs):
            start_time = time.time()
            losses = self._train_epoch(loader, constraints, epoch_idx, show_progress=show_progress, **kwargs)
            train_loss = sum(losses) if isinstance(losses, tuple) else losses
            end_time = time.time()
            if verbose:
                print("epoch %d: train loss %.3f, time cost %.3fs" % (epoch_idx, train_loss, end_time - start_time))
```

The bug is as follows:

```
  File "/home/ruc/xiaotong/OpenDataGen/log/20240310/open-data-gen/src/model/dpautoregressive/dpmade.py", line 401, in fit
    self.net, self.optim, self.train_data = PrivacyEngine(accountant="rdp", secure_mode=True).make_private_with_epsilon( \
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'module'
```

I am confused that I consider module in the function, however it tells me 'module' is missing.

I think this code should be correct.